# Couchbase - getting single bucket information with the java api

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-java-api

Is there a way to retrieve this:

```
 .
 .
 .
"authType": "sasl", 
"autoCompactionSettings": {
    "allowedTimePeriod": {
        "abortOutside": true, 
        "fromHour": 1, 
        "fromMinute": 0, 
        "toHour": 2, 
        "toMinute": 0
    }, 
    "databaseFragmentationThreshold": {
        "percentage": 30, 
        "size": "undefined"
    }, 
    "parallelDBAndViewCompaction": true, 
    "viewFragmentationThreshold": {
        "percentage": 30, 
        "size": "undefined"
    }
}, 
 .
 .
 .
```

see: http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/REST/rest-bucket-info.html
using the java api?

Comment: found it - bucket.bucketManager().info();

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the `BucketManager` can be used to get information on the bucket's configuration through its `info()` method.

You can obtain the manager from the `Bucket` instance by calling `bucket.bucketManager()`.

It also can be used to create views for instance...